# redirectUI in new Web Authentication manager

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, uwp

Is there a way to set the return path/redirectUI in new Web Authentication manager api's as it was in the older Adal Authentication . I getam getting `the reply address mismatch` error.

Comment: Could you please add code of what you've tried.